# Deploy SAPUI5 Application to SAP Cloud or SAP App Center

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

I want to publish/deploy a SAP UI5 application such that it can be used as a Software/Application as a service (multiple companies can use it to fulfill their business requirements).

I am not sure on how to deploy it and where to deploy it (I want it cloud based). I have heard about SAP App center but was not able to find a proper solution for that.

If anyone has done something similar to this, Please share any documentation/platform where I may be able to get a proper solution.

Comment: Check the link [Deploy to Hana Cloud](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/SAP_RDE/frameset.htm?463b52bd34de4549ad05f6282ada02d6.html)

Comment: @santhosh Would this way of deployment work if I need to provide the Application **`xyz`** such that it can be used by multiple companies say company1, company2...companyN?
How the companies gonna access the application deployed on SAP HCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a SAP Cloud Platform you are able to deploy your app and offer it as a service. SAP CP offers full capabilities of hosting/accessing/controling authority/offering the app to others. Pay attention: offering a public app requires contracting with SAP if you take money for it.

Other idea is to host it in DMZ and let people access your SAP NW Launchpad (just theory... security would say "no")

Comment: Can you please confirm that we can provide an app as service by contracting with SAP for a space on cloud with an account. Further, we need to divide that global account into sub-accounts and then by deploying the application on SAP HCP platform, all these sub-accounts created in present and that going to create in future can access the application. Is it so?

Comment: Yes about providing sapui5-as-a-service with userspecific authorization. Chk this https://cloudplatform.sap.com/index.html. Take care, this is not a cheap thing :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to deploy applications or multi-module applications if they have same application lifecycle in form of MTA or Multi-target application. So you can deploy MTA in provider mode in your subaccount and allow subscribers to access your application in their subaccount. Even you can develop frontend and customers can connect to it from their backend. App centre is used if u want to commercialise your application or if you want to find potential customers.